# Performance of nodejs async hooks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Does anyone got some insights about the performance of nodejs async hooks (not storage API, but the general API with before and after) using recent nodejs versions?

The API doc states it "could impact performance", but I can't see any recent benchmark on prod.

Is anyone using it in a promise heavy environment on production and could share some feedback?

Thanks a lot